# Crash on fp-assignment in constructor [C++]

Tags: c++, crash

I have a pretty weird 'crash' at a customer's computer. Using logs I was able to track it to this line of code:

myvar = 1;  //This 'crashes'. myvar is declared as 'double'

The code is obviously okay. But myvar is a member variable of a class. And there is a global instance of this variable and line of code is in the constructor. So it's executed before main(). Not good style, I know...

My questions:
 - Is it allowed to use float/double before main()?
 - Is there some kind of "InitFloatSystem()" function that I could call?

Some more info:
 - It's a Win32 / C++
 - There's no crash message, the program just closes
 - try/catch doesn't help

I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: There's no problem with what you've described. In what way does it "crash"?

Comment: "It's a Win32" - oh Windows? That explains it pretty much.

Comment: You could show some more code to give some context, especially variable declaration etc. Maybe an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, have you run the program in a debugger?

Comment: @sftrabbit: The program just vanishes. No error message.

Comment: How complex is the application? This kind of sounds like you're writing past the end of an array or memory buffer before you hit this line.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: The declaration is pretty simple: "double myvar". The class and the entire project however are both huge. That's why I haven't a simple sample (yet). The debugger won't help here, because it works on my computer... :-(

Comment: @dlp: The application is quite big, the exe is 7MB. The memory idea is good. I'll check that, even though I wouldn't understand why assigned a (non-array) fp-var effectively triggers the crash. But you never know...

Comment: If you wrote past the end of an array or buffer elsewhere and trampled on the memory this variable uses, you may see funky things happen when using this variable. It's a shot in the dark, but if you really are assigning a built-in datatype a constant value and it crashes the app, you may be smashing your stack somewhere else in the code or that may not be where it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, finally found the problem. It's an issue of Visual Studio 2012. I found at the Microsoft website, even though they reported different side effects: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771122/floating-point-math-change-from-vs2008-to-vs2012-affects-native-code-but-not-managed-code

My guess is that the compiler now uses by default processor features that aren't available on some old processors. Using this compiler option magically fixed it:
/arch:IA32

Comment: I guess this was your problem then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#Notable_IA-32_CPUs_not_supporting_SSE2 antique CPU's that don't have SSE2 instruction set support - your exception should have been "Illegal instruction".

Answer (score 0):

Unless your binary is corrupted there is no way a simple assignment should be causing a crash - unless you've overloaded the assignment operator?

What's more than likely is that you've corrupted the heap, or invoked undefined behaviour some where and what you've tracked down is just a side effect of this.

Application Verifier is quite handy on windows for helping track down these sorts of things:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx

But.. its by no means simple to track down the real cause of these sorts of bugs, highest warning levels, warnings as errors and static code checkers help to keep majority of these issues at bay.

Comment: Not the silver bullet that I had hoped for ;-). But I think you're right, so I'll take this as answer to my questions.

Comment: I'd make sure you still have /GS enabled too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8dbf701c(v=vs.80).aspx that *should* pick up any stack based buffer overflows.

Comment: By now I'm pretty sure that it's not a wild pointer. The crash also happens if I move this assignment to a different function. Even happens it's past the constructors in main function. Even happens if the float-variable is a local variable. I still haven't figured it out, but I will post it here if I ever do.

Comment: if you create hello world with the assignment does it crash?